# Pergunta em português respondida em inglês

Tags: discussion, language-choice

É aceitável responder em inglês a uma [pergunta](https://portuguese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40/as-perguntas-est%C3%A3o-sendo-respondidas-por-especialistas?cb=1) feita em português ou vice versa?

What about if I start a misturar inglês with portuguese na same sentence?

Temos aqui um problem? Ou not?

Comment: Já existe uma pergunta do Meta que responde a esta. http://meta.portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/21/should-i-answer-questions-in-portuguese-or-english?rq=1

Comment: @E_net4 Isso leva-nos a outra pergunta [*Perguntas semelhantes, escritas em idiomas distintos, devem ser consideradas duplicadas?*](http://meta.portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/36/122)

Comment: Essa regra não deve ser aplicada ao Meta, cujas perguntas devem ser participadas por toda a comunidade e não levarão a respostas diferentes em função da língua. http://meta.portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/14/84